# Lookup project task list an assign to project with yes/no (array vlookup?)

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I would like to know if any of my projects (A,B,C or D) have ever been associated with certain tasks from another table.

For instance have project A ever been associated with 'pear' in any of the 'project tasks'

I would assume this would require a array formula to look across a long list of project and check if any project 'A* is associated with pear in a 'contain' manner?[image: screenshot of data example]

Comment: What should the result be? TRUE/FALSE, or yes/no, or something else? Doable with COUNTIFS and wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it may be possible that your tasks list includes words within words (using your fruit analogy, eg`Apple`and `Crabapple`

Second, your Project Tasks list needs to be consistant (one choice of seperator, no spaces). So either clean it up manually, or write a formula to do it.  Your choice of separator must not appear in in the task list (if you had a task `do this, or that` then comma wouldn't work) I'll demo the formula

Add a column`J` with this formula

```
=","&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(I2,";",",")," ","")&","
```

Add more `Substitute`s if needed

Then use this formula for the results

```
=COUNTIFS($H:$H,$A2,$J:$J,"*," & B$1 & ",*") > 0
```